# Can Siri be told a ringtone when setting a timer?

Tags: iphone, siri

I normally use the iPhone timer to sleep the device after I've dozed off to some music or podcast. Unfortunately this means that when I ask Siri to set a timer for some cooking, Siri waits the allotted time and turns off the phone rather than notify me that the time is up. Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, looks like Siri pulls whatever is set in the Clock app for its timers.  The only solution is to manually change it in Clock each time.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit messy but you could leave your timer to sleep iPod and and use the 'set alarm for 45 minutes' or wake me up in 35 minutes to use your alarms instead they should always play out loud.